# Spring boot OAuth2 role based access control in resourcse server with roles from Auth Server

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have created an authorization server with spring boot and I want to use roles of resource owners from it in resource server. I have a class **SecurityConfig** extending **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**, where I have checked credentials of resource owners from mongodb for authentication. For that I have a class **MongoAuthProvider** which implements **AuthenticationProvider** from which I am returning an instance of **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken** with username, password and **ROLES** e.g."ROLE_ADMIN" , "ROLE_APPUSER".

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthserverApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AuthserverApplication.class, args);
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("acme")
                .secret("acmesecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code","implicit",
                        "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid");

    }
}

@Configuration
protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MongoAuthProvider mongoAuthProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(mongoAuthProvider);
    }


    @Bean
    public MongoAuthProvider getMongoAuthProvider(){
        return new MongoAuthProvider();
    }

}

@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(OAuth2Authentication user) {
    return user;
}
}

class MongoAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
UserRepo userrepo;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    String userName = authentication.getName().trim();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString().trim();

    User user = userrepo.findByUserNameAndPassword(userName, password);

    if(user != null){
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, password,
                AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN" , "ROLE_APPUSER"));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}

}
```

In auth server I also have a user info rest endpoint :

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(OAuth2Authentication user) {
    return user;
}
```

I want to use the roles of the resource owner from authorization server database in a resource server. For that I have a class **ResourceServer** extending **ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter** inside which I am trying to check user roles from auth server. The resource server is working fine. The problem is it is not able to check roles from auth server.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class AuthserverClientApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthserverClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter  {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**")             
            //.hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help how I can use roles from authorization server in resource server for role based access.

Comment: Can you see my  basic oauth2 project ? https://github.com/andersonkxiass/microservice_oauth2

Comment: Can you provide more info about the problem? any exceptions? logs?

Comment: I am not getting any exception. hasRole("ADMIN") in configure method of ResourceServer is not working, it is giving access denied message to http requests. If I comment has role or replace role to USER from ADMIN everyting works fine.